# Is there a Git Hook for "git status"?

Tags: git, command-line-interface, githooks

I'm writing a CLI and I'd like to run something anytime the user checks "git status". Is this possible? From what I've read there does not exist a hook for this. Is there a possible workaround?

Comment: What would you like to achieve with such a hook?

Comment: Git status currently shows the difference between me & remote. I want to additionally show the difference between whats deployed.

Answer (score 2):

**No.**

There's a complete list of available hooks in [the git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks), and I don't see one there for `status`. That makes sense, since hooks are usually used to take some action before or after changes are made to the local repository. `git status` doesn't change the state of the repository at all, so there's less reason to run a hook when that command runs.

That said, it's possible to create your own `git` commands by putting an executable file named `git-xxx`, where `xxx` is your command name, somewhere in your path. So if you want the status reported differently, you could just create `git-mystatus` to do what you want.

Comment: for precision : built-in commands (`status`, `checkout`, ...) can't be overriden by an alias or a script on the PATH

Comment: Thanks for that @LeGEC -- I've edited that suggestion out.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you for clarifying this! I specifically wan't to run something when the user checks the state of their repo. Is there another way the CLI could listen for "git status"?

Comment: People mean different things when they say *CLI*. Do you mean you're writing a program that acts like (or even is?) a shell, where the user enters commands and your program executes them? If yes, then your program can do whatever you want it to with any input that it gets. If you mean something else, you'll have to explain. Also, it'd be nice to have a concrete example of the kind of *something* that you want to run before `git status`.